# Program still running in Task Manager

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, formclosing

I've almost finished my first C# project apart from this last little *'bug*'; when I run my C# *Winforms* application and close it, the process doesn't end in task manager, it becomes a background task.

Here is how I navigate between forms:

```
Settings form = new Settings();

form.Tag = this;
form.Show(this);

Hide();
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Edit:
Upon looking about, I found each Form has an event property to be ran when the form closes.

Comment: When you say you close the application, what are you doing to close it? Clicking the X [close] button?

Comment: Yes, the Red [X] (top right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accoring to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Environment.Exit Method Terminates the process and returns an exit code to the operating
>   system

```
Enviroment.Exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Settings` form is showed and the `MainForm` is hidden, only when the `MainForm` closes will end the program.

I prefer using `ShowDialog`, since the settings should be shown as a dialog in most programs.

```
Settings form = new Settings();
form.Tag = this;
form.ShowDialog(this);
Hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Settings form = new Settings();
    form.Tag = this;
    form.Show(this);
    Close();
```

Or even:

```
 Application.Exit();
```

Comment: If I do that then my application would end whenever I change forms?

Comment: well if you want your program out of task manager you must end it.